# Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE

Tags: junit, jenkins

I'm stuck configuring tests for Jenkins.  In the Publish JUnit test result report I have test-reports/*.xml but I'm getting the error:

```
'test-reports/*.xml' doesn't match anything: 'test-reports' exists but not 'test-reports/*.xml'
```

When I try **/*.xml I get:

```
Did not manage to validate **/*.xml (may be too slow)
```

When I throw an .xml file into test-reports folder manually it is deleted after the build.

What do?

Comment: by any chance  are you deleting test results as part of build?

Comment: Not intentionally anyway.  Where would this happen?

Comment: What is the value you have in test xml file location?   Note that the input is ant style pattern with workspace directory as root. You may need to see the directory structure under test-reports.  You need to use ** to check files from subdirectory.

Comment: I've tried using the entire directory up the test-reports folder if that's what you mean. Same error occurs.

Comment: please attache the screen shot of the configuration or copy contents of <hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver> from the job's config file. It may help some else looking into this. It is not clear what is 'entire directory' means.

Comment: You claim _When I throw an .xml file into test-reports folder manually it is deleted after the build_ . how is that?

Comment: I have no idea. I put a blank .xml file into the test-results folder and when I build the project the file disappears.

Comment: Here is my config screenshot:  http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y477/Super-Widget/ScreenShot2013-05-28at105618_zpsa0d27c33.png

Comment: I'm following this tutorial btw:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/22816/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-22

Answer (score 0):

It might actually be an issue with XCode.  We figured out that it was actually skipping the application tests and it just wasn't evident anywhere on Jenkins' console output.

Comment: How did you fix this? I m having the same problem

Comment: I am also facing same issue, any solution for this?